# How do I only get the transcript from Watson Speech API?

Tags: python, dictionary, speech-recognition, ibm-watson

I am able to make my code work,however, in my output I receive a nested dictionary and I am not sure how to access only the transcript(words) of the entire wav file?

```
import json
from os.path import join, dirname
from ibm_watson import SpeechToTextV1
from ibm_watson.websocket import RecognizeCallback, AudioSource
import threading
from ibm_cloud_sdk_core.authenticators import IAMAuthenticator

authenticator = IAMAuthenticator('****')
service = SpeechToTextV1(authenticator=authenticator)
service.set_service_url('https://api.us-east.speech-to-text.watson.cloud.ibm.com')

models = service.list_models().get_result()
print(json.dumps(models, indent=2))

model = service.get_model('en-US_BroadbandModel').get_result()
print(json.dumps(model, indent=2))

with open(join(dirname('__file__'), 'nickvoice.wav'),
          'rb') as audio_file:
        print(json.dumps(
        output = service.recognize(
            audio=audio_file,
            content_type='audio/wav',
            #timestamps=True,
            #word_confidence=True,
            model='en-US_NarrowbandModel',
        continuous=True).get_result(),
        indent=2))
```

## My output:

```
    {
      "alternatives": [
        {
          "confidence": 0.97,
          "transcript": "awesome "
        }
      ],
      "final": true
    },
    {
      "alternatives": [
        {
          "confidence": 0.59,
          "transcript": "%HESITATION possible give Charlie meds from me and then "
        }
      ],
      "final": true
    },
    {
      "alternatives": [
        {
          "confidence": 0.86,
          "transcript": "thing else comes up or you have any questions just don't hesitate to call us okay okay thank you so much yeah you're very welcome you have a great rest your day okay you too bye bye "
        }
      ],
      "final": true
    }
  ],
  "result_index": 0
}
```

The above is part of the output. I tried to call just the transcript by doing:

```
print(output['results'][0]['alternatives'][0]['transcript'])
Traceback (most recent call last):



File "<ipython-input-28-fda0a085be69>", line 31, in <module>
    print(output['results'][0]['alternatives'][0]['transcript'])

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

How do I access just the entire transcript without getting other verticals like "confidence","final",etc.

Comment: What do/don't you understand from that error message?

Answer (score 2):

The `results` key in response object is an array so you need to do something like `output["results"][0]["alternatives"][0]["transcript"]`. I am assuming you are saving results in the output, e.g:

```py
output = service.recognize(
            audio=audio_file,
            content_type='audio/wav',
            #timestamps=True,
            #word_confidence=True,
            model='en-US_NarrowbandModel',
            continuous=True).get_result()
print(output['results'][0]['alternatives'][0]['transcript'])


## Updated Example including file handling
with open(join(dirname(__file__), '../resources/speech.wav'),
          'rb') as audio_file:
    output = service.recognize(
            audio=audio_file,
            content_type='audio/wav',
            timestamps=True,
            word_confidence=True).get_result()
    print(output['results'][0]['alternatives'][0]['transcript'])
```

Please check out the [Getting started document](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/speech-to-text-data?topic=speech-to-text-data-basic-response) to understand more about the response object.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-28-fda0a085be69>", line 31, in <module>
    print(output['results'][0]['alternatives'][0]['transcript'])

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Comment: print(output)
None

Comment: `output = json.dumps(...)` is wrong in your example. It should be like the example I posted.

Comment: You are trying to save the output of `print` in `output` that's why when you are trying to print it again you're seeing the error.

Comment: I tried th above changes but still got an error}
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-32-e2fffa338134>", line 31, in <module>
    print(output['results'][0]['alternatives'][0]['transcript'])

TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: Hi again, I think I can see the issue in your code. You need to take `output = ...` statement outside of `print(....)` statement. Please check out the example snippet I provided in answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
print(output['results'][0]['alternatives'][0]['transcript'])
```

if you use the this print above and the audio transcript be none, this code will have this  erro:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

beacuse the results has nothing.

So to resolve this problem verify if the results has something first, like this code below.

```
if(len(output['results']) > 0 ):

    speech = output['results'][0]['alternatives'][0]['transcript']
```